# DataBinding is not Enable in my Custom Property with Dependency Property

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties

I wants to create my own silverlight dll to add to another project.

for this reasin I create a Silverlight LibraryControl Contains some textBox and combobox and also a list of objects ( observable collection type)

I try to Create DependencyProperty Type objects for them.

Now I wants in My second Projects I could be able to fill these Properties with DataBinding but wen I add this to Project the Databinding and some Others was disable to use.

my codes is like below

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty DPDescription = DependencyProperty.Register("DesCription", typeof(string), typeof(WorkFlowPfazar), new PropertyMetadata(Description_Changed));
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(DPDescription);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DPDescription, value);
        }
    }
    private static void Description_Changed(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs Args)
    {
        WorkFlowPfazar wf = Object as WorkFlowPfazar;
        if (wf == null)
            return;
        wf.tbDescription.Text = Args.NewValue.ToString();
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty DPFormNames = DependencyProperty.Register("FormNames", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(WorkFlowPfazar),new PropertyMetadata(FormNames_Change));
    public ObservableCollection <object> FormNames
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(DPFormNames);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DPFormNames, (ObservableCollection <object>)value);
        }
    }
    private static void FormNames_Change(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs Args)
    {
        WorkFlowPfazar wf = Object as WorkFlowPfazar;
        if (wf == null)
            return;
        wf.cbFormName.ItemsSource = Args.NewValue as ObservableCollection <object>;
    }
```

there is some more Properties like these. but I post Two Ones to simle question.
what is the problem? or what shal I do?

Comment: I can has teh codez?  http://images.icanhascheezburger.com/completestore/2008/2/6/ubreakedtehc128467890909707500.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight coding conventions matter.  A field that holds the `DependencyProperty` value for a property should simply have the same name as the property along with the suffix "Property".  Also the name passed to the `Register` method should also match the name of the property.  For example your Description property should look like this:-

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Description",
          typeof(string),
          typeof(WorkFlowPfazar),
          new PropertyMetadata(Description_Changed));

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void Description_Changed(DependencyObject Object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs Args)
    {
        WorkFlowPfazar wf = Object as WorkFlowPfazar;
        if (wf == null)
            return;
        wf.tbDescription.Text = Args.NewValue.ToString();
    }
```